# Linux Named Pipe Mounted on Docker Volume Showing as Regular File

Tags: linux, docker, named-pipes

I am trying to use a named pipe to run certain commands from a dockerised guest application to the host.

I am aware of the risks and this is not public facing, so please no comments about not doing this.

I have a named pipe configured on the host using:

```
sudo mkfifo -m a+rw /path/to/pipe/file
```

When I check the created pipe permissions with `ls -la file`, it shows the pipe has been created and intended permissions are set.

```
prw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Feb  2 11:43 file
```

When I then test the input by catting a command into the pipe from the host, this runs successfully.

Input

```
echo "echo test" > file
```

Output

```
[!] Starting listening on named pipe: file

test
```

The problem appears to be within my docker container. I have created a volume and mounted the named pipe from the host. When I then start an `sh` session and `ls -l` however, the `file` named pipe appears to be a normal file without the `p` and permission properties present on the host.

```
/hostpipe # ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Feb  1 16:25 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Feb  2 11:44 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            11 Feb  2 11:44 file
```

Running the same and similar `echo "echo test" > file` does not work from within the guest.

The host is a Linux desktop on baremetal.

```
Linux desktop 5.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 5 11:43:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And the guest is an Alpine image

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine 
and
Linux b16a4357fcf5 5.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 5 11:43:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 Linux
```

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: How exactly are you starting the container?  What mount options are you using?  What "kind" of Docker is it (Docker Desktop, using core Docker directly, something else)?

Comment: Mount the directory with the pipe, not the pipe file. ` I have created a volume and mounted the named pipe from the host` How exactly? Please post the commands.

Comment: The issue was how I was mounting the volume within compose, I wasn't using the bind type. Got it working now. @DavidMaze, you pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was how the container was being set up. I was using a regular volume used for persisting data not mounting drives and files. I had to change my definition to use the `- type: bind`

Using volumes without the bind parameter does not allow use of the host file system functionality and only allows data sharing.

Before

```
volumes:
  - static_data:/vol/static
  - ./web:/web
  - /opt/named_pipes/:/hostpipe
```

After

```
volumes:
  - static_data:/vol/static
  - ./web:/web
  - type: bind
    source: /opt/named_pipes/
    target: /hostpipe
```